# Filter charts with different datasources in a superset dashboard?

Tags: apache-superset, dashboard-designer

I'm creating a dashboard with different charts that are the result of SQL queries to different tables in kylin.
I cant see how to make a filter (of dates for example) that impact in more than one chart.

This filters need to be linked to the table from where the data its taken but is there any other way to do this? Maybe something like an intelligent filter with JS code?

Answer (score 10):

By default, if you have a filter on a column named `my_col` it will apply on all datasources with a column named `my_col`.

If you want to apply the same filter on a table with a column `my_col` and another table with a column `my_other_col` the easiest way to go is to create a **calculated column** in the second table and name it `my_col` (basically it is like an alias).

In the specific case of date, you can have a **Time Range** filter working on all sources without having to create calculated columns. But you need to specify in all source what is you default date column.

Comment: Can you specify in which version it is not working for you? I run 1.5 and it works

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. For a long time I thought that if two reports in the same dashboard are using different datasets, the same global filter can't be applied to them. I often found myself in a mess while scaling the dashboards.

Happy to confirm that the filter works on all reports as long as the column names are the same.